# Figures are not numbered

Tags: floats, numbering

My question is some boring because I have some problems to give you a minimal work example...

I am writing an archive that uses certain style and I could not post the style here for copyright and ethical reasons.

I am sorry.

Well, at this archive the figures are not numbered! I'd like to know if even without changing the style, I manage to 'force' the numbering of the figures to appear. I can change the preamble.

These are the packets I'm using:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{lastpage}           
\usepackage{indentfirst}        
\usepackage{color}          
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}
```

And this is the form I insert figure:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{aa.PNG}
\caption{AA}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Many thanks.

PS.: At style, all ocorrences of float anf figure are these:

```
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\bfseries LISTA DE ILUSTRA\c{C}\~{O}ES}
...
\AtBeginDocument{\auaddilenv{figure}}
...
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithin{table}{chapter}
...
\renewcommand{\cftfigurename}{\figurename\space} 
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureaftersnum}{\hfill \textendash \hfill} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip} 

...

\renewcommand{\cftfigurename}{\figurename\space} 
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureaftersnum}{\hfill \textendash \hfill} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip} 


\newcommand{\tipoilust}[1]{\renewcommand{\cftfigurename}{#1 \space}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\ilustvaria}{
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{} 
}

\newcommand{\listilustvaria}{
\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{24pt}
\setlength{\cftfigureindent}{0pt}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{} 
\listoffigures*
\endgroup
}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I can compile it either. Your code now contains lots of custom commands without their definition. One of reasons to provide a MWE is that you will find the problem by yourself in most cases when you are removing extras.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin, you comment is important, I'll try!

Comment: @antshar, I'll try! Thank you two.

Comment: you should provide a proper example but try commenting out the line `\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{}`  that prevents figure numbers.

Comment: Please don't add things like `...` that makes it impossible to use your code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you so much, this is the line with problem!! Problem solved!! About the use of `...`, I did not know about that. I am sorry and thank your kind explanation. If you do not matter, you could post as an answer, so I could accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{}
```

defines the figure format to be empty, so you could delete that line.

For comparison the definition in `article` class is

```
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}
```

which typically produces strings such as  "Figure 4"